# Which type of file access to use?

Tags: c++, windows, io

I'm building an io framework for a custom file format for windows only. The files are anywhere between 100MB and 100GB. The reads/writes come in sequences of few hundred KB to a couple MB in unpredictable locations. Read speed is most critical, though, cpu use might trump that since I hear fstream can put a real dent in it when working with SSDs.

Originally I was planning to use fstream but as I red a bit more into file IO, I discovered a bunch of other options. Since I have little experience with the topic, I'm torn as to which method to use. The options I've scoped out are fstream, FILE and mapped file.

In my research so far, all I've found is a lot of contradictory benchmark results depending on chunk sizes, buffer sizes and other bottlenecks i don't understand. It would be helpful if somebody could clarify the advantages/drawbacks between those options.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using a database?
(Eg wrapping SQLLite, within your file)

Comment: The file format will contain a database of sorts but the way its interconnected, i need more control over the file to make it snappy.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the bottleneck is mainly your hardware and not the library you use, since the blocks you are reading are relatively big 200KB - 5MB (compared to the sector size) and sequential (all in one).
With hard disks (high seek time) it could have a sense to read more data than needed to optimize the caching. With SSDs I would not use big buffers but read only the exact required data since the seek time is not a big issue.

Memory Mapped files are convenient for complete random access to your data, especially in small chunks (even few bytes). But it takes more code to setup a memory mapped file. On 64 bit systems you may could map the whole file (virtually) and then let the OS caching system optimize the reads (multiple access to the same data). You can then return just the pointer to the required memory location without even the need to have temporary buffers or use memcpy. It would be very simple.

fstream gives you extra features compared to FILE which I think aren't much of use in your case.